# TS2749: '' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof '? Plaid API

Tags: node.js, typescript, types, plaid

I'm getting the error `TS2749: 'AuthGetRequest' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof AuthGetRequest'?` on this code:

```
const request: AuthGetRequest = {
  access_token: accessToken,
};
```

I've imported `AuthGetRequest` from Plaid, and the code above is exactly the same as in their docs. From the other Stack Overflow questions and responses I've seen it's saying to change my file type from `.ts` to `.tsx` but that wouldn't make sense since this code is inside of my node.js application. I've also seen to change it to

```
const request: InstanceType<typeof AuthGetRequest> = {...}
```

But then it's not using `AuthGetRequest` (it's slightly greyed at import indicating the variable is never used).

Does anyone who's used Plaid have an answer to this or should I just find some weird workaround like what I posted above.

Comment: How do you import the `AuthGetRequest` interface? When you change the `request` type to `any`, does it compile ok?